# $sin(1/x)$: expectation vs infimum

Tags: analysis, probability-distributions, curves, supremum-and-infimum

I want to show that
$$ \underset{Q \in \mathcal{P}^0}{\inf} \  \{\mathbb{E}_{x \sim Q} \sin(1/x)\}  > \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\{ \sin(1/x)\} = -1$$
holds where $\mathcal{P}^0$ is the set of all probability distributions supported on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this possible? I don't have a good intuition of "inf" over the set of all probability distributions.

Comment: What happens if You take $Q = \delta_{x_0}$ (Dirac measure)?

Answer (score 1):

Take any probability distribution $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$, let its associated density function be $f_X$.

Then, $$\mathbb{E}(sin(1/X))=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}sin(1/x) f_X(x) dx$$

So, it immediately follows that

$$|\mathbb{E}(sin(1/X))|=\left|\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}sin(1/x) f_X(x) dx\right|\leq \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|sin(1/x) f_X(x)|dx\leq \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) dx=1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the general answer! I am curious if the inequality can be strict for any function. I thought the specific function I gave could be one example.

Comment: Yes, it is in fact strict. Take the difference of the last two integrals, which becomes the integral of $(1-|\sin(1/x)|)f_X(x)$ , a non-negative function. That integral Will be $0$ if and only if $|1-\sin(1/x)|=0$ almost everywhere, which clearly isn't true

Comment: Thank you! And last question: how do we exclude Dirac-like distributions that attain -1 expectation?

Comment: The Dirac Delta cannot be used as a probability distribution (when using the standard Lebesgue measure). You may use the Dirac Delta as a probability measure, but that is a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

A probability distribution $\mathcal{Q}$ just gives 'weight' to different regions of the real line (hence the names probability mass/density functions). Then $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{Q}[X]$ is just a weighted average of $X$ over the real line. Now think of every possible way you may assign weights over the real line (where every weight is positive and all the weight sums to 1) and then use these weightings to calculate an average over $X$. A stronger statement that you can then prove immediately is "all weighted averages of a set $S$ are lower-bounded by the minimum of $S$", and your original statement is a subcase of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May I show the inequality is strict? Is there a way I can show even Dirac is not applicable? In general I want to see if there is a function that satisfies the above strict inequality, and I thought the topologists’ sine curve ($\sin(1/x)$) could be an example.

Comment: The only way for a distribution to give an expectation of -1 is if all it's mass was concentrated on values of x such that sin(1/x) = -1. The set of such points have Lebesgue measure 0 (think the volume of the set) which makes sense intuitively since every element in that set is an isolated point that doesn't form an interval (roughly speaking). So a function that only assigns weight on such a set is not going to be a distribution with respect to the Lebesgue measure.